# Alexa: REST API call from intent

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to code a simple skill. I'm trying to call Rest API from each intent.

For example:
TM.prototype.intentHandlers = {

```
"startIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
    console.log("startIntent start");   
    // HOW TO CALL get http://mysite.site.com/app/start/1234
    console.log("startIntent end");
    response.ask("bla bla");
},

"endIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
    console.log("endIntent start");

    //HOW TO CALL post http://mysite.site.com/app/end/1234

    console.log("endIntent end");
    response.ask("bla bla bla");
},
```

Can anyone point me how would I called the URLS. I have try in many ways but the it seems that the request never arrived to the server.

Many thanks, Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Repository of Alexa Cookbooks contains a lot of examples. [Performing HTTP calls](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/2243b53/external-calls/httpsGet) one of them.

The cookbook describes itself as:

> AWS Lambda functions running Node.JS can make calls over the Internet
>   to APIs and services using the https module included in Javascript.

It contains [the example](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/2243b5334702046b66cd703543aefa528fbef64a/external-calls/httpsGet/src/index.js) how make HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sample code to call a REST api,

```js
var req = http.get(url, (res) => {
        var body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            var body = JSON.parse(body);
           
            callBack(body)
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        callBack(err);
    });
}
```

Please don't forgot to add the HTTP package like below,

```
var http = require('http');
```